# Error in opening mkb (marmalade) file in mac

Tags: macos, marmalade

Am new to Marmalade, need help in opening a file in mac.
When I try to open .mkb file of marmalade i was getting an error message in terminal like this:

```
running mkb using app from /Developer/Marmalade/6.2/s3e/bin ...  
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object 
at 0x1fe738>)  
Error opening mkb file
```

Comment: Did you try opening any project mkb from example folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered [on marmalade website](https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/8351/problems-in-running-mkb-on-mac.html) there seems to be an issue with folder names.

If the folder (or perhaps the whole path) containing your Marmalade project has any blank spaces (" ") in it, try removing them. Or move the project folder somewhere where there are no spaces in the path.

I had the same issue and removing spaces solved it.

Comment: Even I forgot this one. Thanks, you reminded me of this silly issue